# Listar tabelas pela chave estrangeira no MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Como identificar, por meio uma instrução **SQL**, as tabelas que fazem relação com uma outra, ou seja, as tabelas que possuem uma chave estrangeira que referencia uma outra tabela?

Conforme o exemplo fictício, preciso de uma instrução que mostre como saída a lista de tabelas vinculadas a tabela **produto**, no caso, as tabelas **item_produto** e **estoque**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode obter a lista das chaves estrangeiras passando uma tabela com essa consulta:

```
SELECT
   constraint_name as nome_restricao,
   column_name as coluna_estrangeira,
   table_name as tabela_estrangeira,
   referenced_table_name as tabela_origem, 
   referenced_column_name as coluna_origem

FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'produto'
```

[MySQL - KEY_COLUMN_USAGE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/key-column-usage-table.html)

[MySQL - Information_schema](http://INFORMATION_SCHEMA)